# Variadic class template, multiple inheritance and template unpacking

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

Consider the following simple example

```
struct Banana{

};
struct Apple{

};
struct Watermelon{

};


template<typename Fruit>
struct Stand {
protected:
    Fruit& get();
private:
    Fruit fruit_;
};


template<typename... Stands>
struct TownFairStands : private Stands... {
    template<typename Fruit>
    Fruit& get() {
        return Stand<Fruit>::get();
    }
};

int main(){
    TownFairStand<Banana, Apple, Watermelon> stand;
    TownFairStands<Stand<Banana>, Stand<Apple>, Stand<Watermelon>> stand2;
    return 0;
}
```

The ugly way of defining a `TownFairStand` is the one defined with `stands2`. But I would like the option of the cleaner interface defined with `stand`.

However I am stuck on trying to figure out how I can create this interface

```
template<typename... Fruits>
struct TownFairStand : private ??????{

    template<typename Fruit>
    Fruit& get(){
        return Stand<Fruit>::get();
    }


};
```

What goes in place of `?????`

Comment: `Stand<Fruits>...`

Comment: So simple, guess I didn't know what to google for, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Stand<Fruits>...
```

You want a base class of type `Stand<X>` for every `X` in `Fruits`, so the pattern to expand is `Stand<Fruits>` and that gets expanded by `...` for every element of the pack.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what if Stand<X> and Stand<Y> have different constructor? I tried with a forwarding vararg constructor for TownFairStand https://godbolt.org/g/u5uq33

Comment: That constructor doesn't expand the `Fruits` pack, so it tries to use all the `args...` to construct a single base class of type `Stand<Fruits>` which is invalid (there is no such single base class).

Comment: I guess I need a way to "peel off" args as I pass them in to the constructor of the derived class because this one tries to match the args to each Stand<X> https://godbolt.org/g/w6WVEc

Comment: Yes. Now you're passing every argument to every base class.

Comment: Is there a clean way to pass them off to each Stand<X> or do I have to implement a bunch of SFINAE helper structs?